# SublimeText - CSSLint ignore alphabetical order

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and SublimeLinter CSSLint.

How can I disable the order-alphabetical warnings?

I've found this link:
https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-csslint/issues/15

Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings.

I get this window:

[image]

Then what?

Someone suggested the following code:

```
"linters": {
    "csslint": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "errors": "",
        "excludes": [],
        "ignore": ["order-alphabetical"],
        "warnings": ""
    },
```

I've tried copying and pasting into the right hand pane (// SublimeLinter Settings - User) but I get an error message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Should I paste this into the left pane/window? Do I delete the text "// SublimeLinter Settings - User"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Sublime Text allows comments in its JSON-like settings format, you need to make sure the rest of notation is valid. Hence, your settings should look something like this:

```
{
    "linters": {
        "csslint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "errors": "",
            "excludes": [],
            "ignore": ["order-alphabetical"],
            "warnings": ""
        }
    }
}
```